# php upgrade triggers new warning for sha256

Tags: php, undefined

I just upgraded to php 7.4 and I'm receiving a new warning on my login pages:Warning: Use of undefined constant sha256 - assumed 'sha256'
Here's the snippet:

```
 if(isset($_POST['password'])) {$_POST['password'] = hash(sha256, $_POST['password'].$row_rsSalt['salt']);}
```

What do I do to fix this and remove the warning this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the `sha256` in apostrophes or quotes to make it a string.

Otherwise, PHP is doing exactly what the warning is saying: Looking for a constant named `sha256` and because it didn't find it, it assumes that `sha256` is a string value (and not a constant name).

The correct code is

```
hash('sha256', $_POST['password'].$row_rsSalt['salt']);
```

*Note: It's a bad practice to override values of the superglobal `$_POST` variable. Instead, you should save the value to a regular variable and use that.*

```
if(isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'].$row_rsSalt['salt']);
}
```

Comment: I actually do have it that way, I only posted the offending snip. Thanks for your help and speed. I'll accept your answer.